# how to split a xml format data into row column format in sql server 2008 using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am getting response from asp.net web service as mentioned in below format . I want to convert this in a table format that is age in age column and date in date column. I have asked this question earlier but then it was a string now getting o/p in xml what should i do?

getting response output in @response in this format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://abc.org/">age=7|Date=15/04/2006^age=5|Date=15/04/2008</string>
```

How split this into row column format in sql server 2008 using Stored procedure.I am getting @response as the above mentioned form but unable to use the way i am doing . can anybody help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [string split function](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) of your choice and split on `^` first and `|` second. After that you can use `pivot` to get your data in columns.

```
declare @XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://abc.org/">age=7|Date=15/04/2006^age=5|Date=15/04/2008</string>';

with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://abc.org/')
select P.age,
       P.Date
from (
     select S1.ID,
            left(S2.Item, charindex('=', S2.Item) - 1) ColName,
            stuff(S2.Item, 1, charindex('=', S2.Item), '') Value
     from SplitString(@XML.value('string[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '^') as S1
       cross apply SplitString(S1.Item, '|') as S2
     ) as X
  pivot
    (
    min(X.Value)  
    for X.ColName in (age, Date)
    ) as P;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fabb2/1)

Comment: ha ha ha...u are great!..I have read some of your answer..:)Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in SQL Server, you will have to write a .NET CLR stored procedure that reads your text string, split it by the '|' character and then insert/assign it to your table/object. See this article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)